# Set Default Argument For When Function Takes 2 Arguments and Only One Is Given - Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, arguments

I tried to create some if-statements to catch when the first or second, optional arguments are undefined.

But when only *one* argument is entered, it's still assigning that argument value to the *first* argument. I.e.

```js
function dogBreeder (name, age) {
    if (name === undefined) {
      name = "Steve";
    }
    if (age === undefined) {
      age = 0;
    }
    let newObject = {};
    newObject.name = name;
    newObject.age = age;
    return newObject;
}

console.log(dogBreeder(23));
```

But of course we want it to log:
`{ name: Steve, age: 23 }` instead.

I don't know how to force the name to equal "Steve" when only one argument is given and that argument is a Number.

I also tried:

```js
function dogBreeder (name, age) {
    if (typeof(name) === "number") {
        name = "Steve";
    }
    if (name === undefined) {
      name = "Steve";
    }
    if (age === undefined) {
      age = 0;
    }
    let newObject = {};
    newObject.name = name;
    newObject.age = age;
    return newObject;
}

console.log(dogBreeder(0));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be easier to pass an object, rather than multiple individual parameters - then, you can use default property values:

```js
function dogBreeder({ name = 'Steve', age = 0 }) {
  const newObject = { name, age };
  // manipulate newObject here if needed
  return newObject;
}

console.log(dogBreeder({ age:  23 }));
```

To change your original code, you might use rest parameters and `.find` the argument with the right type (though this is a lot uglier and less likely to be easily usable, IMO):

```js
function dogBreeder (...args) {
  const name = args.find(arg => typeof arg === 'string') || 'Steve';
  const age = args.find(arg => typeof arg === 'number') || 0;
  const newObject = { name, age };
  return newObject;
}

console.log(dogBreeder(23));
```

Comment: What about when a user _does_ enter a name and an age, though? Or is that where I'd manipulate `newObject` if needed : )

Comment: If they enter a name and an age, none of the default values should be assigned, but that doesn't cause any problems - then, the object is just created from each of the passed object's properties.

Comment: Thanks - the second way is working correctly for this specific coding challenge. However, I still can't get the first way to work for when a user enters `console.log(dogBreeder("Jackie", 26));`, for example. It's still assigning the default values to name and age (?)

Comment: You should be passing an object instead, rather than individual parameters. `{ name: 'Jackie', age: 26 }`, It's a lot easier to read *and* parse

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. For this particular challenge, random parameters do get passed in, so it probably makes more sense to use rest parameters and `.find()` the arguments with the right type.